# Dropping observations in Stata based on certain characters in their label

Tags: stata

Is it possible in Stata to delete observations from a variable based on whether they include certain characters within their label? For example, in `sysuse auto` how can I delete all observations in `foreign` that end in "ign". The expected result here is that all observations classified as "Foreign" within the `foreign` variable would be dropped.

I tried converting `foreign` into a string (using `tostring foreign, replace`) so I could use `drop if strmatch(foreign, "*ign*")==1` but this resulted in no observations being deleted because `foreign` has value labels, which are lost when converting to string. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `decode`:

```
clear all
sysuse auto

decode foreign , gen(foreignstr)
drop if strmatch(foreignstr, "*ign")
```

Note that if you want strings that *end* in "ign", you can omit the second asterisk from your `strmatch()` function.

While it's not necessary for this problem, note that you can access and work with value labels using Stata's local macro extended functions -- see `help extended_fcn`.

An example of this method:

```
clear all
sysuse auto

levelsof foreign , local(levs)
foreach l of local levs {
    local val : label `: value label foreign' `l'
    drop if foreign == `l' & strmatch("`val'", "*ign") 
}
```